# Must an iOS Bluetooth LE read or write be done first before readRSSI, to get the latest RSSI value?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Or, does iOS Bluetooth in the background do a little communication now and then between central and peripheral, and automatically, periodically update peripheral.RSSI, so that it stays current?

Or, is it necessary to call [peripheral readRSSI] with its callback peripheralDidUpdateRSSI?

I've poured over the Apple BTLE docs and googled a lot, but can't find answers to these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there's no auto updating of RSSI given to the app side. Just connect the peripheral. Discover the peripheral's services. Set the `CBPeripheralDelegate`. Call `readRSSI` and wait for the delegate callback.

I suggest putting `readRSSI` on a timer if you want to keep it up to date for UI elements. However, I recommend not making your timer fire faster than ~ 2 seconds. Otherwise you'll end up with a bunch of errors informing you it couldn't read the RSSI.

Comment: After I discover and connect, I skipped discover services, and started doing readRSSI and getting callback every couple seconds.  However, after about 55 seconds, I get the 'no connection' error.  Happens every time I run it.

Comment: I haven't tried that, but it's most likely because you haven't initiated a pairing request with the peripheral (and actually locked down the channel, so to speak)